# Typescript use string or string[]

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I have this definition:

```
interface Field {
  question: string,
  answer: string | string[],
}
```

but theres error in my text editor if i do this:

```
if (typeof answer === 'string') {
  const notEmpty = answer.trim().length > 0
}
```

it says string[] doesn't implement trim. is my approach wrong? should i use 2 interfaces? thanks

updated:

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: const notEmpty = (answer as string).trim().length > 0

Comment: What do you want the logic to be if `answer` is an array? Check that all of them are empty?

Comment: @aron if its array, i want to check answer.length > 0

Comment: @KonstantinSamarin that will throw a runtime error if `answer` is an array.

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCbIN4BQyyAjgK4QDOYwA9iAFzLVSgDmANEcnCJQO7QmLdsgA+zMKxBsA2gF0uAXwIEYZEAhr1kMWrQAUADybos2AJT5uxBPWr5eA6EuQBeZEYDcN5MBjIBmAAngAOELQBToJQ7m4eAOQiMglWhMQZGXZ8YMggtGAAogC2oSHuPHwxAHRSwMUGFtWYEDJgABbIAHzIAAy+KipAA)

Comment: Actually I've just noticed that you're already doing the check `typeof answer === 'string'` before trying to call `.trim()`... are you sure this is what your code looks like?

Comment: It seems like a lot of complexity could be solved by just making the property always be an array.  An array can have only one element, there's no reason it can't.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/zwOOEw) your error.  Please provide a [mcve] which actually demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Typescript complains because it could also be a string and strings don't have a `trim` method.

Comment: @Gh05d except that per my and jcalz's comments, it *doesn't* complain...

Comment: Maybe something in your Typescript options? Because I often see this problem in files in our projects when we do the same thing.

Comment: What typescript version?

Comment: Please replace images of code with actual text so that others can use it to demonstrate the issue for themselves.  See [ask] and specifically [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: It's probably that `i` is of type `number` and the compiler doesn't know how to narrow based on that. Without a [mcve] though I'm not going to go through the effort of demonstrating this.  If you want to increase your chances of getting a helpful response, I suggest you follow the guidelines in [ask], specifically about providing a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because you use a variable : `i` to go throught your object.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCbIN4BQyyAjgK4QDOYwA9iAFzLVSgDmANEcnCJQO7QmLdsgA+zMKxBsA2gF0uAXwIEE9ajz6CoAQShQ4ATybos2WQHJeA6JfkLkAXmRXIlewG5V6vmGTAzsgADN4EwDDIABRgRgAOELSRNjr6hkaywPLOTi6WIjKWAJT43L6aILRgAKIAtnGxQSnQacaZ8gB0UsC1UUUdmBAyYAAWyAB8IQRKQA)

```
interface Field {
  question: string,
  answer: string | string[],
}

const answerArray: Field['answer'][] = ['tes'];

const i = 0;

if (typeof answerArray[i] === 'string') {
  const notEmpty = answerArray[i].trim().length > 0
}
```

---

Between the two line :

`if (typeof answerArray[i] === 'string') {`

`const notEmpty = answerArray[i].trim().length > 0`

TypeScript consider that `answerArray[i]` could result in different values.

---

The soluce is to store the value inside of a pointer, like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCbIN4BQyyAjgK4QDOYwA9iAFzLVSgDmANEcnCJQO7QmLdsgA+zMKxBsA2gF0uAXwIEE9ajz6CoAQShQ4ATybos2WQHJeA6JfkLkAXmRXIlewG5V6vmGTAzsgADN5qGv4Atka62tBBNjr6hkaywPJhwDDIABRgRgAOELTZ0bG2UM5OLpYiMpYAlPjcvpogtGAAopEF+UFlcVAAdFLAkTkNQ5gQMmAAFsgAfCEESkA)

```
interface Field {
  question: string,
  answer: string | string[],
}

const answerArray: Field['answer'][] = ['tes'];

const i = 0;

const myAnswer = answerArray[i];

if (typeof myAnswer === 'string') {
  const notEmpty = myAnswer.trim().length > 0
}
```

Comment: thank you so much,,, how is this possible ?!

Comment: Where did this code come from? That's not in the question...

Comment: @Aron I did retro engineered it based on the code provided by OP.